# send the URL onload by post request in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

first time using the site to ask a question I'm new to chrome extensions so I'm sure I'm making some mistake i apologize in advance

I'm tring to send the current tab's url onload by post request i only can make it send the url by submit how can i  send it in the loading of the page automatically

here is my code

**manifest.json**

```
       {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Phishing tool",
      "description": "This extension send url to server to check for phishing",
      "version": "1.0",

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "http://localhost:8080/ph/FirstServlet*"
        ]
    }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="p.js"></script></head>
<body>
<object width="200" height="50" ></object>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/ph/FirstServlet" method="POST">


link:<input type="text" name="first_name"> <br /><br />
<input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>
<button id="myBtn"> click here to display the url</button> </p>
<h1 id="demo">Url displays Here</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**p.js**

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        var tabURL = tabs[0].url;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function(){
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/ph/FirstServlet");
        xhr.send(tabURL);
    });
});
```

i tried it but when i click on the plugin icon it show no response from the server

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to send the url from your **popup page (extension process)** to your server and your server url is `SERVER_URL`, you would need to do the following things:

1. Add `SERVER_URL` in `permissions` field in `manifest.json` file, for your case, it would be

   ```
   "permissions": [
       "http://localhost:8080/ph/FirstServlet/*"
   ]
   ```
2. Make an ajax call in your `popup.js`

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
           var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
           var formData = new FormData();
           formData.append("first_name", tabURL);

           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.onload = function(){
               console.log(xhr.responseText);
               // Your logic
           };

           xhr.open("POST", SERVER_URL);
           xhr.send(formData);
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: i tried your javascript but it didn't work, maybe i did something wrong by the way I'm  newbie in javascript if you can give extra details i will be appreciate it

Comment: @sultan, could you have a update mentioning what you have tried and what's the error info?

Comment: i did what you told me and it doesn't send the url

Comment: @sultan, when you are saying the url is not sent, what do you mean? Did you find any error output in the console? And have you tried to output something in `xhr.onload` callback to test it?

Comment: i mean onload it doesn't response but when i use the post submit in my html code it response i didn't find error how can i try something in xhr.onload sorry I'm new in javascript and ajax

Comment: @sultan, never mind, try `console.log(xhr.responseText);` inside onload callback

Comment: i tried it no response can you look to my code above and tell me what is wrong

Comment: @sultan, you could open F12 tool to view if the request is sent. Considering you said it worked well when you click the submit button, mayby your server only respond to form data. I have edited the answer to send form data.